# CSS Change X position of text tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have the following text tag which i cannot change. I want the "test" text to be centered using CSS only.

```
<text 
  width="13.89" 
  height="13.89" 
  x="291.46999999999997" 
  y="156.55" 
  transform="rotate(0,277.78,142.86)" 
  text-anchor="end" 
  style="fill: rgb(255, 0, 0); font-size: 5pt; display:inline-block; position: relative; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(50%, -50%);"
>
  test
</text>
```

Via a javascript function the text gets an x and y on the bottom right center of a rectangle.

I'd like to move this to the middle center of that rectangle, The only thing we can control is the CSS, seeing as every rectangle is the same size i believe something like left -15px and top -15px should do the trick.

Is there any way to achieve this using CSS only?

Comment: Not only is `text` not a valid HTML element, but you need to show the JavaScript you are working with.

Comment: In order to move an element there needs to be a position relative/absolute set. I do not see that in the CSS.

Comment: Probably an SVG [`<text>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text) element

Comment: "I have the following text tag which i cannot change". In your case the solution seems complicated/dirty if you respect your first statement. Is there really no way you can change this ?

Comment: Hello, This is indeed an svg element i'm sorry for not mentioning that. the x and y are filled in using the data-bind though we do not have control over this.

Comment: We do not own the code which generates the page we only have the ability to change the banner / header and the content ( html and css). If we fill in javascript in the form it will delete it automaticly. Since it'll take some time for our supplier to adjust this we'd like to fix this ourself in the meantime by changing the position using css since that's the only thing we are able to do. The position is absolute inherited from div though the text element does not listen to left and top attributes.

Comment: You are all so quick to say that a text element doesn't exist, yet **[HTML5 allows custom tags to be created](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/)** ...

Comment: You could try adding a CSS transform to the <text>

Answer (score 2):

To reposition a `<text>` element within an `<svg>` with hardcoded `x` and `y` properties, using CSS, you can use [transform: translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) to offset the element from its hardcoded `x,y` position.

Examples

```
/* move 10px left */
.textElementSelector {
  transform: translateX(-10px);
}

/* move 5px down */
.textElementSelector {
  transform: translateY(5px);
}

/* move 10px up and right */
.textElementSelector {
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't comment on how the `text` tag doesn't exist.

If you want to move it, you need to display it as inline block, in a relative position.

```
text {
  display: inline-block:
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

- `inline-block` to take only the needed space
- `relative` to allow the element's placement
- `50%` to put the top-left corner of the container at the center of the parent
- `translate(-50%, -50%)` to put the container at the center of the parent

Comment: You can override it, or replace `left` with `right` (and set translateX to 50% instead of -50%). And to answer you, I don't know how it will behave ... In an absolute positioning, this would stretch the element's width, but I don't know in a relative position.

Comment: Yeah my bad anyway, deleted my comment because the right prop is defined for the background position

Comment: Most of this answer is not applicable to SVG <text> elements.

Comment: Hi,
I have made an simple example of this: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FNS5QS1L5RWI
I tried using the transform function but looks like the text isn't changing positions.